# Uploading files: FileUpload.SaveAs or manually writing FileUpload.FileBytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, file-io

Using the `FileUpload` control, please explain the difference between the following two methods of uploading file:

**1. Using the `FileUpload.SaveAs()` method:**

```
fileUploadControl.SaveAs(path)
```

**2. Writing a byte array to disk from `FileUpload.FileBytes` using `File.WriteAllBytes()`:**

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileUploadControl.FileBytes);
```

How would these compare when uploading large files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These both have different purposes.
`SaveAs` lets you save as a file directly while `WriteAllBytes` gives you a byte array of contents.

Your file upload control will receive the bytes only after the file has been uploaded by the client, so there will be no difference in upload speeds.

A byte array is a value-type, so if you are passing copies of that around, note that it will create copies in memory whenever you pass it to functions.

I would use `FileUpload.FileBytes` when I want to access the bytes directly in memory and `fileUploadControl.SaveAs` whenever all I want to do is write the file to disk.

Comment: So if the user had to upload a 100mb file, using the second option would then load a 100mb byte array into the server's memory?  The first option would not do this?

Comment: The 100MB of the file would be in the server memory in both cases. But when you pass around the byte array you would end up creating copies of 100MB each.

Comment: So how would you go about uploading a huge file (1Gb, for example)?  Is there a better way of streaming the upload to disk instead of holding all the data in memory before saving occurs?

Comment: You can't do that in html4. In html5 I guess you could use websockets to stream the file.

Comment: Which option is best for Uploading file with reference to consistency. I used fileUploadControl.SaveAs(path) sometimes this approach results in corrupted files. If I use the second method does that solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387257/some-times-pdf-files-get-corrupted-after-file-upload-c-sharp