# Some times PDF files get corrupted after File Upload C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, file-upload

I am trying to upload PDF files. Only sometimes uploaded file gets corrupt. When I open that file on Adobe or browser. its says **Insufficient data for an images**

[image: Error Pdf]

This problem is not for all the uploads.  When I tried to upload the same file again its works perfectly.
  I am not able to replicate the issue so that I can know why this type of issue occurring
    I am using below code to save the file

```
FileUpload upload = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;

if (upload.HasFile)
{
     string nameoffile = upload.FileName;
     Random ran = new Random();
     int forReference = ran.Next();

     string[] strfileArray = nameoffile.Split('.');

     nameoffile = strfileArray[0] + "" + forReference + ".pdf";
     upload.SaveAs(path + "/" + nameoffile);
}
else
{
     upload.SaveAs(path + "/" + nameoffile);
}
```

Note: We are running this appliaction on  Azure VM. This code was works without any issue on previous server. since we migrated to Azure

Comment: What is the size of the file? What is the max request buffer length? Try uploading the file asynchronously.

Comment: File size is 1.5 MB and max request length is     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/> . some times upload fails for small files too. The files above 20 mb works without any issues

Comment: This is Adobe pdf software version problem please update your Acrobat and try again. Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: ``Only sometimes uploaded file gets corrupt.`` Please check and compare the size in bytes of file on your server with the original source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had hosted application on C drive of azure VM. After Changing application to secondary storage i.e. D drive problem got resolved